# How do I change line breaking in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to set the breaking of line so that the line breaks in the middle of words (to maximize compactness) like:

```
This is a long word: pseudo-
pseudohypoparathyroidism
```

instead of:

```
This is a long word: 
pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism
```

Im using MS Word 2010 on XP if that matters.

Comment: Have you turned on hyphenation? It's possible that Word doesn't know how to hyphenate words such as those. You can include soft-hyphens in them to give Word an idea where to break them.

Comment: Thanks, I guess what I really needed was to know the word "hyphenation" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this on words not already in Microsoft Word's dictionary, you need to put the word in ALL CAPS. Then go to Page Layout > Hyphenation > Hyphenation Options and enable hyphenation, also check the box for "Hyphenate words in CAPS".

There does not seem to be any other way, as Microsoft Word does not recognize where the syllables are on technical / medical terms such as what you used. Good catch!